# Inserir os últimos dados de uma tabela em uma segunda tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web

Estou com um problema pra dar INSERT em PHP. Tenho uma tabela chamada produtos_1 e outra chamada produtos_2. A tabela 1 tem os mesmos produtos que a segunda, mas com 5 produtos a mais, ou seja, ID 11, 12, 13, 14 e 15 não estão inseridos na produtos_2.
Preciso "copiar", inserir esse 5 produtos, de uma vez, na produtos_2. E toda vez que houver produtos a mais na tabela produtos_1.

TENTEI ISSO, MAS ELE INSERE SOMENTE O ID 15, O ÚLTIMO >

```
if (!$db->Query("SELECT * FROM produtos_2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) 
    $db->Kill();

while (! $db->EndOfSeek()) {
    $row = $db->Row(); 
    $idprodutos2= $row->id;
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO produtos_2 SELECT * FROM produtos_1 WHERE id > '.$idprodutos2.'");
```

"Vamos juntos ao avanço"

Comment: Se você precisa manter as duas tabelas idênticas, não seria melhor utilizar um Trigger dentro do banco de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso os ids tenham o mesmo valor em ambas a tabelas ex id 1 - café. Pode fazer a diferença da tabela produto1 pela produto2 e usar o resultado como insert de uma vez so.

```
Insert into produto2(id, descricao)    
select id, descricao from produto1 
where not exists ( select id from produto2 where id = produto1.id)
```

Comment: PERFEITO! Deu certo :0

Answer (score 0):

Essa instrução só inseriu o último, pois está usando LIMIT 1, se vc souber quantos registros precisa copiar altere o LIMIT.
Dê mais detalhes sobre o processo, essa rotina faz parte de uma verificação externa à operação de cadastro, ou precisa ser em tempo real como uma tabela espelhada?

Para o segundo caso, um bom recurso seria o uso de gatilhos (triggers), pois vc pode montar facilmente um comando "Insert Into Select" e o MySQL se encarega de disparar a trigger sempre que necessário.

Ref.: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Espero ter ajudado, se precisar eu posto um exemplo pra vc

Comment: #JotaSantana, meu grande. Obrigado pela vontade de ajudar. Vamos lá...É uma requisição via JSON de um dispositivo móvel. Na verdade o produto_1 é um parâmetro String que vem de uma função Java armazenado via POST, então fiaria assim >

   if (! $db->Query("SELECT * FROM `{$_POST['emails']}` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")) $db->Kill();
    while (! $db->EndOfSeek()) {
        $row = $db->Row(); 
        $idPost= $row->id; 
     
    }


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `{$_POST['emails']}` SELECT * FROM post WHERE id > '.$idPost.'");

Comment: Quando ponho um limite maior, ele varre o ID da coluna correspondente a ordem. LIMIT 1, úlimo id 15 no echo. LIMIT 5, 10º ID no echo. Isso que não entendo. Ele apresenta somente um valor!

Comment: É uma operação externa.

Comment: Pelo código que vc postou, creio que o "Insert" tem que estar dentro do loop, como ele está depois a variável acaba ficando com o último id da lista (usando Limit 5)